What exactly is P-value and what is its relation with the significance level?
The formal definitions I have seen differ but the one I thought I understood was: "the probability of an observed or more extreme result assuming that the null hypothesis is true".
Let's say X claims to have a special die that consistently rolls the number 6, 4/6 of the time. My null hypothesis (H0) is that this claim is false. After conducting several tests under the assumption he is wrong, I obtain extreme results of 3%. With a significance level of 5%, if extreme results occur only 3% of the time and fall below the significance level, shouldn't we accept them? Why is it the other way around?
I could follow the formula but it is going against my beliefs (which is wrong) so I really want to understand. I have googled and read but none of the definitions are making sense to so that is why I made my own example to see if someone can point where my misunderstanding lies.
Thanks for your time.

"$H_0$ is that he is wrong", what specific probability are you using to calculate the $p$ value?

@wjmccann I am just giving a random example (it might not be a good one so you could give your own example). I am not calculating any p-value I am just trying to understand the relationship between p-value and significance level.

The only description of p-values I have ever understood is https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1421257436569112579.html , which may help. You've determined that your null hypothesis is extremely surprised: it only assigns 3% probability to what you saw. You've decided up front that if your null hypothesis assigns 5%-or-less probability to the summary statistic, then it's "too surprised" and so you reject it. (Whether there's any other hypothesis that is less surprised - assigns higher probability to your observed summary - than the null hypothesis, is a completely different question.)

Here is the general form of a $p$-value computation: you decided on a summary statistic ("proportion of times $6$ was rolled") which maps the space of available data ("sequences of dice rolls") onto an ordered set ($[0,1]$). Then you pick a hypothesis (such as "the die is fair"), which you suggestively name the "null hypothesis" (but as far as the formalism goes, this was arbitrary).
Now you do your experiments, collect your data, compute the value of the summary statistic, and you discover that in fact this hypothesis is very surprised by the value of the summary statistic: you worked out the value it took on all possible values of the summary statistic over all possible data that your experiment could have yielded, and discovered that the null hypothesis only assigned 3% probability that the summary statistic would take a value as extreme as (or more extreme than) the value you computed.
Up front, before running the experiment, you decided that if the hypothesis assigned less than 5% probability to "the summary statistic you ended up with, or more extreme than that", it would be "too surprised" by the summary and you'd say "yeah that hypothesis is probably false". Note that:

you are saying nothing about almost any other hypothesis: declaring that you are rejecting the null hypothesis doesn't by itself give you any licence to accept any other hypothesis. (How could it? We haven't yet computed anything about what any other hypothesis thinks of the data - maybe your other hypothesis is even more surprised by the summary statistic than the null hypothesis was!)
there's nothing special about the "null hypothesis" in the formalism; it's just suggestively named, but you are free to set it to anything you want.


In your particular example, you chose a null hypothesis "does not roll a $6$ two-thirds of the time", which is an extremely complex hypothesis, encompassing enormous ranges of behaviour ("rolls a $6$ two-thirds of the time, for the first ten thousand throws, then switches to being fair", "rolls a $1$ always", "is fair", …). I don't know how you'd even go about computing how surprised this hypothesis was at any given summary statistic - I'd hope it has some relation to the hypothesis's negation, but it's not obvious to me - and it's not clear to me what it means for the value of your summary statistic "proportion of times $6$ was rolled" to be "more" or "less" extreme. (But it is well past midnight for me, which may explain this.)

(The only description of p-values I have ever understood is https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1421257436569112579.html by Nate Soares, which may help you conceptually.)

Thank you so much for this!

It's basically giving the null hypothesis the benefit of the doubt.  Essentially, for a 5% significance level, if there is a $\geq$5% chance that, if the null hypothesis is true, we would get the results of our experiment by chance variation, this isn't sufficient "proof" to reject the null hypothesis.  If there is a <5% chance of getting our results by chance variation if the null hypothesis is true, then we consider this "proof beyond a reasonable doubt" and reject the null hypothesis, in this case for the alternative hypothesis, but this may not be a good idea as the alternative hypothesis could also be wrong, as explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eesUdFlYMh8
